# How can one swap elements which come from a function?

Tags: python, function, swap

So I have defined a class called "Particles":

```py
class Particle:
    def __init__(self, posInit, momInit, spin):
        self.posInit = posInit
        self.momInit = momInit
        self.spin = spin
    def momfT(self, t):
        return self.momInit*(math.cos(t))-self.posInit*(math.sin(t))
    def posfT(self, t):
        return self.posInit*(math.cos(t))+self.momInit*(math.sin(t))

P = [Particle(posInit = i, momInit = j, spin = choice(["up", "down"])) for i,j in zip(Zinitial,Pinitial)]
```

What I now want to do is switch the positions of the particles if a certain condition is met.
So something like the following:

```py
if cond==True:
  P[1].posfT[t], P[2].posfT[t1] = P[2].posfT[t1], P[1].posfT[t]
```

But the above does not work since I am trying to assign to a function a value.

So I am not sure how to do this?

Comment: If you want the two `Particle` objects to trade `posInit` attributes, you could do something like `P[t].posInit, P[t1].posInit = P[t1].posInit, P[t].posInit`

Comment: I want them to switch position attributes (posfT not posInit) specified for a time t

Comment: just in case: use `cond is True` or `==` for comparison

Comment: Yes corrected that.

Comment: What are `t` and `t1`? Also, adding an example of the desired input and output would help.

Comment: t and t1 are numbers. Even before running the code-checker gives "Can't assign to function call"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you intend to store the position and momentum of your particle over time in `posfT` and `momfT` respectfully *(edit: I previously thought you wanted only the current position)*. If so, they should not be methods, but attributes. You should also have separate methods to modify those values as t evolves. I suggest to modify your class like this:

```py
class Particle:
    
    def __init__(self, posInit, momInit, spin):
        self.posInit = posInit
        self.momInit = momInit
        self.spin = spin
        self.momfT = dict()
        self.posfT = dict()
        self.calc_at_time(0)
    
    def calc_at_time(self, t):
        self.momfT[t] = self.momInit*(math.cos(t))-self.posInit*(math.sin(t))
        self.posfT[t] = self.posInit*(math.cos(t))+self.momInit*(math.sin(t))
```

**Note: I am assuming that posfT and momfT are initialized with t=0. I absolutely lack the knowledge to know if this is correct, please check and correct as necessary.** I am focusing on code here.

You will then be able to set new positions at time t by calling `calc_at_time(t)`

```py
t = 1
t1 = 2
P[1].calc_at_time(t)
P[1].calc_at_time(t1)
P[2].calc_at_time(t)
P[2].calc_at_time(t1)
```

And access the position of P[x] at time t with `P[x].posfT[t]`.

Accordingly, what you're trying to do should now work:

```py
if cond == True:
  P[1].posfT[t], P[2].posfT[t1] = P[2].posfT[t1], P[1].posfT[t]
```

Meaning: posfT of P[1] at [t] becomes posfT of P[2] at t1, and reciprocally.